# Criar menus no Dashboard do WordPress

Tags: wordpress

Preciso criar menus customizados para um tema WordPress e cheguei a esta `function` que funciona em partes, pois não aparece a parte de **"TÍTULO"** e campos de **"TEXTOS"** ou **"SIDERBARS"**, sabem me dizer onde estou errando?

```
// Function para novos menus
function theme_options_panel(){
   add_menu_page(
       'Theme page title', 
       'Artigos', 
       'manage_options', 
       'theme-options', 
       'wps_theme_func'
   );
}

add_action('admin_menu', 'theme_options_panel');

function wps_theme_func(){
    echo '<div class="wrap"><div id="icon-options-general" class="icon32"><br></div>
    <h2>Insira um artigo</h2></div>';
}
```

Isto é o que acontece:

[image: Resultado]

Answer (score 2):

As funções `add_menu_page` e `add_submenu_page` são assim mesmo, se você quiser preencher aquela interrogação terá que personalizar tudo a partir do `<h2>Insira um artigo</h2>`.

Mas o que você procura são [Tipos de Posts Personalizados](http://codex.wordpress.org/pt-br:Tipos_de_Posts_Customizados). O seguinte código cria um TPP. Observações:

- o domínio `meu-tpp` é usado para tradução, confira a documentação [Translating WordPress](http://codex.wordpress.org/Translating_WordPress). Mas se quiser pode remover todas as funções `__()` e `_x()` deixando as *strings* limpas.
- confira também os vários parâmetros que podem ser usados no [`register_post_type`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type#Arguments), especialmente na array `'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', etcetera )`.
- para personalizar ainda mais o TPP, usaremos [*Custom Meta Boxes*](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box), que podem ser registrados na opção `register_meta_box_cb` (desabilitada no exemplo abaixo). Ver um [exemplo](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13903529/1287812) no SO.

```php
add_action( 'init', 'criar_artigos_sopt_9881' );

function criar_artigos_sopt_9881() 
{
    $labels = array(
        'name' => _x( 'Artigos', 'post type general name', 'meu-tpp' ),
        'singular_name' => _x( 'Artigo', 'post type singular name', 'meu-tpp' ),
        'add_new' => _x( 'Add New', 'artigo', 'meu-tpp' ),
        'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Artigo', 'meu-tpp' ),
        'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Artigo', 'meu-tpp' ),
        'new_item' => __( 'New Artigo', 'meu-tpp' ),
        'all_items' => __( 'All Artigos', 'meu-tpp' ),
        'view_item' => __( 'View Artigo', 'meu-tpp' ),
        'search_items' => __( 'Search Artigos', 'meu-tpp' ),
        'not_found' =>  __( 'No artigos found', 'meu-tpp' ),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No artigos found in Trash', 'meu-tpp' ), 
        'parent_item_colon' => '',
        'menu_name' => __( 'Artigos', 'meu-tpp' )
    );

    $args = array(
        'labels' => $labels,
        'public' => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'show_ui' => true, 
        'show_in_menu' => true, 
        'query_var' => true,
        'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => _x( 'artigo', 'URL slug', 'meu-tpp' ) ),
        'capability_type' => 'page',
        'has_archive' => true, 
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'menu_position' => null,
        'taxonomies' => array('category'),
        'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'comments', 'custom-fields', 'thumbnail' ),
        //'register_meta_box_cb' => 'my_meta_boxes'
    );

    register_post_type( 'artigo', $args );
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Obrigado, funcionou perfeito.